# Declarative-form based authentication - validating username and password

Tags: java, security, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Using form based authentication and authorization in `JEE` webapps. In web.xml I specify security constraints, declare security roles and login configuration (`<form-login-page>,<form-error-page>`). So, when user tries to access secured jsp or servlet, user is being redirected to login page, where if entered credentials are invalid, user is redirected to `error.jsp` (declared under `<login-config><form-error-page>` tags).

This way I can only notify user that login details are invalid, but can't specify is it wrong password entered or entered unknown username. I can only leave a message like `"Wrong username and/or password!"`

Is there a way to implement validation of username and password, with form based security approach, so I could display appropriate error message? (For example, if user have entered existing username but password doesn't match. Or if entered username doesn't exist).

Comment: Why would you want to differentiate between user name and password being wrong? You are leaving yourself open to attack if you do that.

Comment: @mikea Well, I thought that I should leave a message appropriate to situation, something like: `This username is not registered`. I remember I was in similar situations on some sites, where I forgot which email address I was using to log in to my account. Good example is `www.outlook.com` site. When I enter some email address that is not registered on `@hotmail.com`(and some password), I will get message: `That Microsoft account doesn't exist. Enter a different email address or get a new account.`

Comment: hmm, that's not what I see when I log on there: I get email address or password is incorrect, which is what I'd expect.

Comment: @mikea That is what I am getting if I type some `something@hotmail.com` email address that is not registered. And if I type valid email but wrong password I am getting: `That password is incorrect. Be sure you're using the password for your Microsoft account.`